# Outlook - export mail to text on rule of vba

Tags: email, text, outlook, export, rule

I am pretty sure that this has been done before.

Does anybody know how to export emails, into text files on to my c drive, i know how to move emails into other folders in outlook but on my c drive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `MailItem.SaveAs` Method. You specify the path and file type.

Ex:

```
Sub SaveEmail()

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem

  ' assume an email is selected
  Set msg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

  ' save as text
  msg.SaveAs "C:\MyEmail.txt", olTXT

End Sub
```

The file type is a `OlSaveAsType` constant. Press F2 in the VBA Editor and paste this into the search box for the list of possible values.

Comment: excellent thanks, How can you export specific line from the email to Excel. I get emails everyday. I want to export specific line  of new data to bottom of column(last row) in excel.