# Save email to Windows folder with subject as file name

Tags: vba, outlook

I want specific emails (tickets) to be saved to a folder.

My search sent me to this post ([Macro to save e-mail as text file, to be used in a rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611665/macro-to-save-e-mail-as-text-file-to-be-used-in-a-rule)).

When I try to make the output the Subject line I get

> Outlook cannot complete the save due to a file permission error.

With SenderName or Time/Date it works.

```
Public Sub SaveEmail(msg As Outlook.MailItem)
    ' assume an email is selected
    Set msg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    ' the 2nd and 3rd options work but the 1st does not
    ' msg.SaveAs "C:\" & msg.Subject & ".msg", olTXT
    ' msg.SaveAs "C:\" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".txt", olTXT
    msg.SaveAs "C:\" & msg.SenderName & ".txt", olTXT
 End Sub
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a subject line? I’m mostly wondering if a subject line contains illegal characters and/or violates character limits in Windows file names.

Comment: Aren't you passing a **MailItem** to this `Sub SaveEmail()`? Why did you change it to whatever selected? What if the selected isn't a mail item?

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28025657/Vba-Code-Eliminate-Illegal-Characters-from-a-filename.html

Comment: @JoeyGrant "R1-Min User Service Ticket TICK00" plus 4 digits after the two zeros.

PatricK Honestly, I'm not entirely sure. I kept playing with it until it worked with my rule. I assumed that because it only runs on an email that it'd work?

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: @braX Didn't notice your message at first but it was exactly what I needed! Thanks! Now IDK how to mark your answer as correct since the "check" doesn't appear where I believe it should be.

Comment: @ChadBelerique I have added an answer for you to mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all characters can be used in a Filename. Namely, these.

```
Asterisk (*)
Backslash (\)
Colon (:)
Angle brackets (< >)
Question mark (?)
Slash (/)
Plus sign (+)
Pipe (|)
Quotation mark (")
```

There are lots of places online to find a pre-written function which will remove or replace them. Here is one: [Remove Illegal Characters from Filename](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28025657/Vba-Code-Eliminate-Illegal-Characters-from-a-filename.html)